# Why will this R package not install and how can I fix it?

Tags: r, fortran, devtools, roxygen2, r-package

I would like to include a Fortran subroutine in an R package. I have always only built packages using devtools and roxygen (so my knowledge may be pretty limited). I am getting an error that prevents me from the package getting installed after it has been built about it not being a Win32 application...

I am using Rtools 3.3. My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] roxygen2_5.0.1 devtools_1.9.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.2   Rcpp_0.12.1   memoise_0.2.1 stringi_1.0-1 stringr_1.0.0 digest_0.6.8
```

To initially build the package, I run this:

```
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)

setwd("C:/panterasBox")
create("myPack")
setwd("C:/panterasBox/myPack")
dir.create("C:/panterasBox/myPack/src")
```

This is the fortran code, saved as myFunc.f in the `/src` file:

```
         subroutine myFunc(x)
         implicit none
         real(8) x

         x = x + 2

         return
         end
```

The R wrapper I am using to call it (saved in the `/R` file):

```
#' @title A test
#' @description a test function.
#' @param x this is a number
#' @useDynLib myPack
#' @export
myFunc <- function(x){
  if (!is.loaded('myFunc')) {
    dyn.load("/src/myPack.dll")
  }
  myCall <- NULL
  myCall <- .Fortran("myFunc", x=as.double(x), PACKAGE="myPack")
  return(myCall$x)
}
```

Now, to create the documentation and install the package, I run this:

```
> document()
Updating myPack documentation
Loading myPack
Re-compiling myPack
"C:/Users/pantera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
"C:\panterasBox\myPack" --library="C:\Users\pantera\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQdJJko\devtools_install_1df837dd6c29" --no-R  \
--no-data --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch --no-test-load 

* installing *source* package 'myPack' ...
** libs
gfortran -m64     -O2  -mtune=core2 -c myFunc.f -o myFunc.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o myPack.dll tmp.def myFunc.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -lgfortran -LC:/Users/pantera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/pantera/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQdJJko/devtools_install_1df837dd6c29/myPack/libs/x64
* DONE (myPack)
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Updating roxygen version in  C:\panterasBox\myPack/DESCRIPTION 
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing myFunc.Rd
> install("myPack")
Installing myPack
"C:/Users/pantera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
"C:/panterasBox/myPack" --library="C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'myPack' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack/libs/x64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack/libs/i386/mypack.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I have also tried to build and check the package via the command line using `R CMD build myPack` and then `R CMD check myPack_*tar.gz`. The only error I get doing that is something about my LaTeX package.

Thank you for reading this, and I appreciate any help offered.

Disclaimer: I did ask this question previously, but I wanted to ask again in a "minimal fashion".

Comment: At a quick glance, I see that you should at least do `return(myCall$x)` (instead of your current `return(mycall$x)`).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks. That was sloppy on my part. It didn't fix the problem, but I fixed this.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing i386 and x86_64 files? `unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack/libs/i386/mypack.dll':` contains `i386` but you have compiled for 64bit.

Comment: Try to switch to 32bit R and redo, I still suspect you mixed i386 and x86_64 binary. Use `R.version` to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clear that this is an architecture issue. Looks like x64 version of your package (which is probably what you need) was built successfully, but x86 build and, thus, the overall task, failed.  Try the following:

1. Add `--no-multiarch` option to `install` call. This will tell `RCmd` not to build for x86, because your main arch is x64.
2. (Probably, optional, but just for convenience.) Add `--no-test-load` option to `install` call. This will tell `RCmd` not to judge success of the build task by success of loading the package.
3. Load the package manually with `library('myPack')` and see if it works.

To summarize, replace your `install` call with:

```
install('myPack', args=c('--no-multiarch','--no-test-load'))
library('myPack')
```

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer. Totally worth the bounty:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are loading `dyn.load("/src/myPack.dll")`

but during install it is looking for:

```
'C:/Users/pantera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/myPack/libs/i386/mypack.dll'
```

*(i.e. no capital P)*

*Sorry I don't have enough rep to put that as a comment.

Comment: This got rid of the warning and note I posted about the `Undeclared package in foreign function calls`. I updated the question, thanks.